# Trigger 2nd form submit click after another Observable is done

Tags: javascript, forms, angular, rxjs, observable

Here is the simple procedure we would like to do with and only with use of `RXJS Observables`:

1. Click Login button (form with username & password). `Observable.fromEvent` is bound with our form.
2. After submitting the form, call `loginUser()`, which sends http request to server and returns Observable.
3. if HTTP request is in progress: Clicking login button should not trigger another login request.
4. if HTTP request is NOT in progress: Clicking login button should trigger another login request.

`take(1)`, `takeUntil()`, `takeLast()` didn't helped us. So what is the proper way to stop the login executing if we click the Login button 5-times in 500ms and make it available again, after `loginUser()` completes?

This should be doable with Observables only, the only problem is the last part, described in previous sentence.

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flatMapFirst` or `exhaustMap` as it is known now. The idea behind it is that each click will create a new Observable which will subsequently be flattened out. It will silently drop any new events while one is in progress.

```
Observable.fromEvent(submit, 'click')
  .map(() => {}) // Login values
  .exhaustMap(credentials => loginUser(credentials))
  .subscribe(x => console.log("Logged in!"));
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly! Thank you so much for your answer.